# Xubuntu 13.10: disabling suspend on lid being closed

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, suspend

I'm having trouble with configuring my home server. I have an old lenovo x200 laptop that runs Xubuntu 13.10.

My problem is that after closing the lid the laptop is begin suspended despite changing all lid-related options in power management to "nothing". How to disable all actions (except turning the screen off) on lid close?

Comment: This is the actual bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1222021

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem, affecting the power button as well. This worked for me:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xfce#xfce4-power-manager

/etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
HandlePowerKey=ignore
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Comment: How does the "Ask" setting translate into logind.conf's language? The man page mentions "ignore, poweroff, reboot, halt, kexec, suspend, hibernate, hybrid-sleep, lock" as options only.

Comment: Works like a charm. I noticied when you put "ignore" into logind.conf the xfce4-power-manager-settings works properly.

Comment: It's enough to only use _HandleLidSwitch=ignore_

Comment: Thanks a bunch. :) And yes, only `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` is enough.